# Função passandoPor está dando erro nos testes

Tags: javascript, lógica, for

Execute uma função chamada passandoPor que imprime no console "aqui eu tenho o valor de x" onde x será o valor de i em cada iteração, para cada valor de 0 a 3.

Só que dá essa mensagem de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vocês poderia verificar, se o código abaixo está correto:

function passandoPor()
{

for (var i = 0; i <4; i++){

```
console.log("aqui eu tenho o valor de ",i);
```

}

}

passandoPor();

Comment: também foi perguntado aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/424900/exerc%c3%adcio-repeti%c3%a7%c3%a3o

Comment: aqui pra mim este código rodou normal, voce rodou no navegador ?

Comment: Sim, no navegador do Google Chrome funciona normalmente. No console do site funciona também, só que quando faz o teste da erro.

Answer (score 0):

Voce esqueceu de concatenar sua frase no `console.log` com o simbolo de `+`

```
function passandoPor() {
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    console.log("aqui eu tenho o valor de " + i);

  }
}
```

Comment: O problema ainda persiste!

Comment: @gabriel não precisa concatenar com o + a , já o fez neste caso